# .htaccess redirect with query string variable

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect a URL like
`http://sample.com/view_image?v=random key like youtube`

to

`http://sample.com/view/?v=random key like youtube`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root you can do either:

```
Redirect 301 /view_image /view/
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/view_image$ /view/
```

Or you can use mod_rewrite if you already have rules and you don't want mod_alias directives conflicting with your existing rewrite rules:

```
RewritRule ^/?view_iamge$ /view/ [L]
```

The `?v=something` query string will automatically get appended to the end in all three cases.